# Set All UILabels Hidden

Tags: objective-c, css, ios, xcode

Is there a way to set all UILabels as hidden in Objective-C? I'm showing and hiding labels based on `if` statements and feel like I'm writing really bulky code. Is there a way to select all UILabels to `setHidden:YES` a la CSS?

Edit: I need one of them visible at a time, not all hidden at once.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your labels lay at the same view you can use it's `subviews` property:

```
for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        subview.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

And if there are numerous of views with labels you can even add a category to the whole `UIView`.

```
@interface UIView (HideLabels)

- (void)hideAllLabels:(BOOL)hide withExcludedLabel:(UILabel *)label;

@end

@implementation UIView (HideLabels)

- (void)hideAllLabels:(BOOL)hide withExcludedLabel:(UILabel *)label
{
    for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
        if (subview != label && [subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            subview.hidden = YES;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

There's no other way to do this.

Edit: the code above updated according to your needs.

Comment: This looks like it might fit what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you only need 1 `UILabel` at all time, you can reuse the same `UILabel`. The advantage is you use a bit less memory and you don't need to manage all the `UILabel`s. The disadvantage is that you need to recalculate/store the coordinates to put the `UILabel` and stores the content of the `UILabel` (the management is shifted to this).

---

Now that the requirement has changed, the below answer is no longer valid. However, I still keep it there, in case anyone wants to ***hide/show all labels***.

<s>I don't think you can do it like CSS, but we can use a trick to avoid having to loop through all the `UILabel`s to `setHidden`.</s>

You can put all the `UILabel`s as subview of a transparent `UIView`. The `size` and `origin` of the transparent `UIView` should be configured so that the coordinate is the same as when you don't use the transparent view (to avoid confusion). When you want to hide all `UILabel`s, you can just hide the whole transparent `UIView`.

This has a drawback is that all the `UILabel`s must be on top or under the existing view. This means that you cannot freely adjust some label to be on top of certain element, and some label to be below certain element on the existing view. You need to create another view for that purpose, and things will get quite messy there.

Comment: This would work, but I need to have only one of the Labels visible at a time. The way that I understand it, hiding the view would hide them all as well, but showing one would either not work or would reveal all of the labels still with `setHidden:NO` from before. :/

Comment: @Sneagan: You didn't mention this in the question! Well, if you only need 1 UILabel visible at a time, is it possible to reuse a single UILabel for everything?

Comment: Sorry! Can you change the content of a label dynamically? That could fix the problem entirely! (Edited the question. Sorry again)

Comment: @Sneagan: Of course, but you need to recalculated the coordinates, and know what content to be replaced.